# Background image that worked before Laravel 6.0 doesn't display

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a view that has a `<body></body>` that should show a background image. I did it before but now it doesn't work. The background image is downloaded on my computer and it is in the public folder of the project in my Laravel instance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ACAVUCAB</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 56px;
            background-image: url(fondo_cerveza1.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .dropnegro {
            color: #141519;
            text-align: center;

        }
        nav.navbar {
            background: #141519;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #424448, #B7BCCD);
        }
        .tamano {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .tope {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .centro {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your image located exactly? In the `public` folder? Did you check the console to see if there's any 404s?

Comment: Is any of your other HTML being applied? If so, have a read of [Relative Paths in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) and try this instead: `background-image: url("fondo_cerveza1.jpg");`

Comment: Looks like you might just be missing the `"` around the `fondo_cervezal.jpg` image

Comment: The url works in other projects but not in this one

Comment: Yes the other html is being applied

Comment: I put the (" ") but still doesnt work

Comment: This could be an issue with a relative path. What happens if you do `url("/fondo_cerveza1.jpg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the relative path. I have to do `url("/fondo_cerveza1.jpg");`